# URLTask does not send any UrlRequest

Tags: swift, url

I am new to swift and doing a project in swift 4.0 to acquire data form Fitbit API and got a Strange problem, my url task does not send any urlrequest any more but skip all the code until task.resume, and do not give anything back. Can anyone helps me plz. The code is shown below

```
import UIKit
class FitbitAPI{
static let sharedInstance : FitbitAPI = FitbitAPI()

var parsedJson : [Any]? = nil


func authorize(with token: String){
    let accessToken = token
    let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/steps/date/today/1m.json")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:baseURL!)
    let bodydata = "access_token=\(String(describing: accessToken))"
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Bearer \(String(describing: accessToken))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpBody = bodydata.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {[weak self] (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        if let data = data, error == nil{
            do {

                self?.parsedJson = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [Any] )
                print(String(describing: self?.parsedJson))

            }catch _{
                print("Received not-well-formatted JSON")
            }

        }
        if let response = response {
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

        }


    })
    task.resume()
 }
}
```

Comment: It's synchronous. The closure `[weak self] (data, response, error) in` will be called after.

Comment: Thx for your help. I will try to make the task asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

As @Larme implied in his comment, all of that code between the `let task =` line and the `task.resume()` line is a callback. Meaning it won't get called until the task completes. Put breakpoints inside of that callback (like on your `if let error = error line`), and see if they get hit.

ALso, your URL task is a local variable in this method. That means it's entirely possible that its getting released from memory right at the end of this method, before the callback can even be executed. You'll need a reference to the task outside of the method if you want to guarantee that it stays alive in memory long enough to hit the completion callback.

Comment: Thx for your help, I tried to put breakpoints, xcode just ignore the breakpoints within it.  I did initialise parsedJson at the start of those code, is there anything else that I can do to make the memory stays alive long enough? Thanks again for your patience and advise

Comment: Well Xcode isn’t ignoring your breakpoints. That’s not a thing. To keep it alive in memory, you need to assign the task (not the JSON) to a variable that lives beyond the scope of your method. In this case, a property on FitBitAPI would be the most likely location. So create a property like `private var authorizeAPITask: NSURLSessionDataTask?`

Comment: It's not ignoring. If you put a breakpoint at `if let error = error`, but imagine that you server is slow, it could take a few seconds before hitting the breakpoint while your app continue to live elsewhere.

Comment: ^ what @Larme said

Comment: Sry fall in sleep yesterday, the breakpoints still not works, so i tried to run it in a play ground, however the play ground does not give any output on that line and jumped to the end as well

Comment: Btw, when I first write this code, it runs perfectly, and then I was trying to build a tableview to show the data I got, and this problem came out. Hope this can help you identify my problem.